# What is the type of "start_routine" passed to pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads

Here is an example of creating a new thread in C:

```
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp){
   //
}
   
int main(){
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

From `linux man pages` I can see that `pthread_create` is defined as the following:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
                          const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
                          void *(*start_routine)(void *),
                          void *restrict arg);
```

Here are my questions:

1. what is the type of `start_routine`? is this a *pointer to a function pointer*?
2. What is the type of `*myThreadFun`? same as above? a pointer to a function pointer?
3. Why can't `pthread_create` just take in a normal *function pointer*?

Comment: [`void *(*start_routine)(void *)`](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+*%28*start_routine%29%28void+*%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what is the type of `start_routine`? is this a pointer to a function pointer?

No, this is *just* a [simple] pointer to a function:

```
void *(*start_routine)(void *)
```

This is a pointer to a function that takes a `void *` pointer as an *argument* and has a *return* type of `void *`

Perhaps this would be more clear with:

```
int (*intfunc_routine)(void *)
```

Here it's more obvious that the return type of the function/pointer is an `int`

Although the return from the thread function is a `void *`, this is more like a "return code". The usual return is `return (void *) 0;` for success and (e.g.) `return (void *) 1;` for error. This is analogous to the return value for `main`

> What is the type of `*myThreadFun`? same as above? a pointer to a function pointer?

Once again, `myThreadFun` is just a function of the type previously mentioned. When one does:

```
myThreadFun()
```

It is a *call* to the function.

Just doing:

```
myThreadFun
```

(*without* the parenthesis) is the *address* of that function (i.e. a pointer to the function).

> Why can't `pthread_create` just take in a normal function pointer?

As we can now see, it *does* just take in a "normal" function pointer

---

**UPDATE:**

> So you are saying `int (*intfunc_routine)(void *)` is equal to `int * (*intfunc_routine)(void *)` ?

No, they are *not* equivalent. The first is a pointer to a function that returns `int`. The second is a pointer to a function that returns a *pointer* to an `int` (i.e. `int *`).

> There is extra asterisk in front of int in the beginning. That's what start_routine looks like, it has an extra asterisk in the beginning. – Dan

The syntax:

```
return_value_type (*func_pointer)(anyargs);
```

The `(*func_pointer)` specifies a pointer to a function. `return_value_type` can be any valid type (e.g. `void`, `int`, `char *`, `double`, etc.). The `anyargs` are the parameter list to the function pointed to by `func_pointer`.

Consider a forward declaration of (e.g.) `malloc`. This will be in `stdlib.h` and you can also see it in `man malloc`:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
```

To convert this to a function pointer (e.g):

```
void *(*pointer_to_malloc)(size_t size);
```

Here's a small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

// pointer to function that is compatible with malloc
void *(*pointer_to_malloc)(size_t size);

void *
safe_malloc(size_t size)
{
    void *ptr;

    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"safe_malloc: malloc failure size=%zu -- %s\n",
            size,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    return ptr;
}

int
main(void)
{

    // we can do this ...
    pointer_to_malloc = malloc;

    // but we like this function better
    pointer_to_malloc = safe_malloc;

    // now anyone can do this ...
    int *arr = pointer_to_malloc(128);

    printf("main: arr=%p\n",arr);

    free(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say the _usual_ pthread return codes are analogous to process exit codes, with zero for success and one for error? Maybe for your code, but I find your convention quite unusual.

Comment: @pilcrow One can use whatever convention one wants. But, SO is replete with instances of using that particular convention. And, given OP's issue, it might be better to keep things simple, rather than introduce more complex/advanced uses of the return value.